# Is there a way to overwrite a page's <title> tag by using PHP within the body?

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to PHP and was wondering if there was a way to overwrite what is displayed in a title tag by using PHP inside the body.

Let me explain why I'm trying to do this. I'm using a forum/cms software that allows me to create PHP pages, but won't let me change anything about the header (including the title tag). I was hoping there was a script that I could place into the body using PHP that would overwrite whatever was displayed into the default title tag.

This is probably a crazy question, and if so I apologize.

Just running out of ideas how to get what I need in the title.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into the DOM. This is quite simple with that.

Comment: Echo JavaScript into the body to rewrite the DOM document title.

Comment: you need to edit or change the  forum/cms software that you use

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. If one of the answers was what you needed, kindly mark it, for future visitors looking for the same question.

Comment: It's making me wait 10 minutes. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.

if you want to change it add some Java Script code that will execute on the client side and do this for you:

```
 <script>
 document.title = "This is the new page title.";
 </script>
```

And with some PHP:

```
<head><title>some title</title></head>
<body>
   <?php if (some condition, etc) { ?>
   <script>
        document.title = "This is the new page title.";
   </script>
   <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow... thank you! Did exactly what I needed. Do you know how this would impact SEO?

Comment: It's not good for SEO, since the engines usually go over the clean HTML, and don't execute your javascript code.

Comment: while it may 'work' its not great practice, best to edit the original code.

Comment: @Amirshk is that still the case, even with the huge amount of ajax loaded content these days?

Comment: @Dagon, I agree, but this is an answer for the question. Without info on the CMS, I can't offer a better one.

Comment: I'm using IP.Board for the forum software, and IP.Content for the CMS (made by InvisionPower).

Comment: @MarcelGwerder good point, I'm not sure about that. I seem to recall the SEO goes over the META fields first. Since the ajax is usually for content, I assume it has to do the queries.

Comment: @user2268107, don't know that CMS. But I have to agree with the others that there might be a better solution, like changing the forum's code.

Comment: The main reason I'm doing this is I want the name to change dynamically depending on an input into a form (using GET). Some of these pages are already indexed by Google, so I will give it a few days and let you guys know if their results take on the new title. Then we will know one way or another!

Comment: Just a quick update in case you all were wondering. After a couple days, Google has reindexed the sites and their search results are now showing the new page titles (with JavaScript!).

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?
            echo "<script>document.title='Hello, World!';</script>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```